# moving platform with gameplay kit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, gameplay-kit

Creating a 2d game, and want to add moving platforms where I can control the pattern and rotation of the platform.

Example:

[image: Moving Platform]

I want this platform to move in a clockwise motion, also when it reaches the top and bottom I want it to rotate accordingly as if it is facing the direction it is going (so the platform would essentially rotate 180 degrees as it arches at the top and bottom).

I can't use SKActions because I need the physics to work properly.

My idea is that I can use an Agent with behaviors and goals to do this. Not sure if I will need path finding as well.

I'm researching how to use these features, but the documentation and lack of tutorials is hard to decipher. I'm hoping someone could save my some time of trial and error by providing an example of how this would work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: SKActions would not cause the physics to not work properly,  it would behave the same as using a scriptable path.  Also, you do not want pathfinding, because you already know the path, so it does not need to be found.

Comment: If my player is on a horizontally moving platform via an SKAction, won't my player just slide off? Because the SKAction movement happens outside the physics.

Comment: Honestly, I do not know,  never attempted it.  But the action goal approach is going to leave the same problem

Comment: I believe it does, so currently I move platforms manually by adjusting the velocity and position of the node. I was thinking with the agent approach, I could use the agents positions to adjust the components position and rotation. Which then game me a thought of giving an invisible node the skactions, and then I use that nodes position to update the real object I want to change.

Comment: You know for your platform problem you can always just make your sprite a child of the platform,  this way when the platform moves, all children move with it

Comment: Ya, but I want the player to be able to slide around on the platform, and be affected by other nodes if the player comes in contact. Allowing this interaction to happen with physics saves me from coding those interactions. My true goal is to get moving platforms to follow any path I want... horizontal and vertical platforms are easy adjusting them manually, but to do interesting paths is another story...

Comment: slide as in slide to a stop...

Comment: welcome to why physics engines and platformers suck...

Answer (score 1):

Using SKActions or adjusting the position manually will be sucky to get working the way you want, BUT it's always worth a shot to give it a go, since it would take 2 minutes to mock it up and see...

I'd suggest doing something like a `Path` class that sends velocity commands to the platform every frame ...

Actually, this could be a good exercise in learning the state machine..

> MOVE RIGHT STATE: if X position > starting position X + 200, enter state "move down"
>
> MOVE DOWN STATE: if Y position < starting position Y - 200, enter state "move left"
>
> MOVE LEFT STATE: if X position < starting position X, enter state "move up"
>
> MOVE UP STATE: if Y position > starting position Y, enter state "move right"

.. there are ways you could figure out to give it more curvature instead of just straight angle (when changing direction)

Otherwise you would have to translate that into a class / struct / component and give each platform it's own instance of it.

///

Another option is to take the physics out of the equation, and create a `playerIsOnPlatform` property... then you manually adjust the position of the player each frame... (or maybe a SKConstraint)

This would then require more code on jumping and such, and turns things to spaghetti pretty quickly (last time I tried it)

But, I was able to successfully clone this, using proper hit detection going that route:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cnhlFZeIR7Q

### UPDATE:

Here is a working project:
https://github.com/fluidityt/exo2/tree/master

Boilerplate swift stuff:

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit


// Workaround to not having any references to the scene off top my head..
// Simply add `gScene = self` in your didMoveToViews... or add a base scene and `super.didMoveToView()`
var gScene = GameScene()

class GameScene: SKScene {

  override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    gScene = self
  }

  var entities = [GKEntity]()
  var graphs = [String : GKGraph]()

  private var lastUpdateTime : TimeInterval = 0

  func gkUpdate(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) -> TimeInterval {
    if (self.lastUpdateTime == 0) {
      self.lastUpdateTime = currentTime
    }

    let dt = currentTime - self.lastUpdateTime

    for entity in self.entities {
      entity.update(deltaTime: dt)
    }

    return currentTime
  }

  override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    self.lastUpdateTime = gkUpdate(currentTime)
  }
}
```

### Here is the very basic component:

```
class Platforms_BoxPathComponent: GKComponent {

  private enum MovingDirection: String { case up, down, left, right }

  private var node: SKSpriteNode!

  private var state: MovingDirection = .right

  private lazy var startingPos: CGPoint = { self.node.position }()

  @GKInspectable var startingDirection: String = "down"
  @GKInspectable var uniqueName: String = "platform"
  @GKInspectable var xPathSize: CGFloat = 400
  @GKInspectable var yPathSize: CGFloat = 400

  // Moves in clockwise:
  private var isTooFarRight: Bool { return self.node.position.x > (self.startingPos.x + self.xPathSize) }
  private var isTooFarDown:  Bool { return self.node.position.y < (self.startingPos.y - self.yPathSize) }
  private var isTooFarLeft:  Bool { return self.node.position.x < self.startingPos.x }
  private var isTooFarUp:    Bool { return self.node.position.y > self.startingPos.y }

  override func didAddToEntity() {
    print("adding component")
    // can't add node here because nodes aren't part of scene yet :(
    // possibly do a thread?
  }

  override func update(deltaTime seconds: TimeInterval) {
    if node == nil {
      node = gScene.childNode(withName: uniqueName) as! SKSpriteNode

      // for some reason this is glitching out and needed to be redeclared..
      // showing 0 despite clearly not being 0, both here and in the SKS editor:
      xPathSize = 300
    }

    let amount: CGFloat = 2 // Amount to move platform (could also be for for velocity)

    // Moves in clockwise:
    switch state {

    case .up:
      if isTooFarUp {
        state = .right
        fallthrough
      } else { node.position.y += amount }

    case .right:
      if isTooFarRight {
        state = .down
        fallthrough
      } else { node.position.x += amount }

    case .down:
      if isTooFarDown {
        state = .left
        fallthrough
      } else { node.position.y -= amount }

    case .left:
      if isTooFarLeft {
        state = .up
        fallthrough
      } else { node.position.x -= amount }

    default:
      print("this is not really a default, just a restarting of the loop :)")
      node.position.y += amount
    }
  }
}
```

### And here is what you do in the sks editor:

[image]
[image]

Comment: I have an idea to get it to work. Currently I have a dummy spritenode that I animate with followPath. Using UIBezierpath, I can give it a custom path of my choosing. I get my actual platform to update its position to this dummy spritenode and it will follow the path. I'm thinking instead of updating the position of the platform, I come up with an algorithm that can apply the specific velocity to move from where the platform is to where the dummy node is by using the difference between the two... This is the concept that I'm going to research and attempt to figure out.

Comment: I'll have to test this out. but, in the  update function, I will have 2 points to work with. Platform position, dummyNode position. Using the difference between the two points, I can change the velocity of the platform to move the platform towards the dummyNode. This happens in the physics world so my player will move accordingly on the platform with out any additional variables or changes. Tonight I will have to test this out...

Comment: @Discoveringmypath ?? what?? dummyNode wasn't in the question, now I'm confused

Comment: Right, I'm just considering what it would take to get it to work. My question would be how to get this task done using agents and gameplaykit.

Comment: yeahhhh idk why you want to use AI for this.. that would be more complicated... I am posting an update to my question with code.. IT'S a very basic component that I threw together real quick like... it's not pretty (but for a first attempt at making a component I think it came out OK) @Discoveringmypath, the platform moves in the outline you drew.. you can tweak the component to make it more rounded, or change to counterclockwise, etc... and convert it to physics.. this was just a quick test to prove concept

Comment: I also had an idea on how to add entities via the editor, but entities are supposed to have nodes, not the other way around I think :P but that could probably be arranged as well

Comment: Thanks for the update, moving the position of the node happens out of the physicsworld, so a node on top will just slide off, when it is moving left or right... If instead of adjusting the position, we adjust the velocity it should solve this... I'm going to play with it tonight..

Comment: @Discoveringmypath i know that... this was just easier to set up to show you :P this is a VERY basic component